# select values which coincide with all the elements of the list

Tags: mysql

How to make mysql requst to select all values, that contains all elements of list.
I have table like this:

```
+--------+------------+
| carID  | serviceID  |
+--------+------------+
|   1    |      12    |
+--------+------------+
|   1    |      13    |
+--------+------------+
|   1    |      15    |
+--------+------------+
|   2    |      12    |
+--------+------------+
|   3    |      13    |
+--------+------------+
|   3    |      15    |
+--------+------------+
```

I make request like:

```
SELECT `carID` FROM `car_services` WHERE `carID` in (1, 2, 3) AND `serviceID` in (12, 13, 15);
```

but it returns all cars, but I need just car with `carID = 1`, because only this car suitable for the condition (support all services 12, 13, 15).

Any ideas?

Comment: is serviceid is unique for a carid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be `group by` and `having`

```
SELECT `carID` 
FROM `car_services` 
WHERE `carID` in (1, 2, 3) AND `serviceID` in (12, 13, 15)
group by carID
having count(*) = 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
SELECT `carID` 
FROM `car_services` 
WHERE `carID` in (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY `carID`
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN `serviceID` in (12,13,15) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a compound where clause to individually check EXISTS is pretty straightforward and not dependent on the uniqueness of the serviceid-carid relationship. I look at the query plan/execution cost before deciding this was actually better than the the grouping solutions if it unique.

```
SELECT carID
  FROM car_services a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM car_services b WHERE a.carID = b.car_id AND serviceID = 12)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM car_services b WHERE a.carID = b.car_id AND serviceID = 13)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM car_services b WHERE a.carID = b.car_id AND serviceID = 15)
```

NOTE: This clearly doesn't scale well for lots of required services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT carID
FROM (
  SELECT carID, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT serviceID ORDER BY serviceID) AS allServices
  FROM car_services
  WHERE serviceID in (12, 13, 15)
  GROUP BY carID ) t
WHERE allServices = "12,13,15";
```

This will work even if you have duplicates in `serviceID` field.